# Need a less repetitve way to start Rails on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, automation

I've been on a Mac just over a month and before that I've been using Windows and wrote a .bat file to run a few other little .bat files to fire up MongoDB, guard start for livereload, rails server, and a rails console. And it lastly launches e-texteditor which opens that rails dir as a project.

I hope this is the right place to ask and not superuser. So what is one way I can automate these things on Mac? -- Currently, I launch 1 terminal window with 4 tabs. tab 1 runs 'mongod', tab 2 runs 'rails s', tab 3 runs 'guard start', tab 4 runs 'rails c'. then I open one more tab and do 'mate .'

Comment: I see that this question is flagged/voted as 'close' once. totally fine, just wanted to know in which of the stackexchange I should move this to, if anyone can suggest that'd be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) is your best friend.

Step 1: Install foreman

```
gem i foreman
```

Step 2: Create a file named `Procfile`

```
rails: rails server
mongo: mongod
guard: guard start
```

Step 3: Run `foreman start`. It will automatically start all 3 servers. If you press `Ctrl-C`, all servers will be terminated.

Step 4: Run `rails c` in another terminal.